# Negative part of the integrand in an iterated integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Hi everyone: Suppose that $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ and  $(Y,\mathfrak{N},\nu)$ are two measure spaces and $f(x,y)$ is an extended real valued measurable function on $X\times Y$. Suppose we can not apply Fubini to $f$ but we know that the two iterated integrals
$$\int_{X} \int_{Y}fd\nu d\mu$$ and 
$$\int_{Y} \int_{X}fd\mu d\nu$$
exist in $(-\infty,+\infty]$. Can we conclude that the iterated integrals (or at least one of them) of $f^{-}$ is less that $+\infty$, i.e.
$$\int_{X} \int_{Y}f^{-}d\nu d\mu<+\infty?$$
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you saying that the existence of the iterated integrals doesn't say anything about the integral of the positive and negative parts? Can we have a case where both iterated integrals are finite but the product integral is $\infty-\infty$?

Comment: You should have commented on my answer, so I'd be notified. As I wrote there, every time the iterated integrals are unequal, the  $\infty-\infty$ situation occurs. For a concrete example with finite iterated integrals, see Wikipedia: [Failure of Fubini's theorem for non-integrable functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's rather the opposite. Assuming the spaces are $\sigma$-finite and $f$ is measurable, Tonelli's theorem applies to both $f^+$ and $f^-$, and asserts the equalities 
$$ \iint_{X\times Y} f^+=\int_X\int_Y f^+  =\int_Y\int_X f^+ \tag1$$
$$\iint_{X\times Y} f^-=\int_X\int_Y f^-  =\int_Y\int_X f^-\tag2$$
(where the integrals could be $+\infty$).

So, how can equality fail for $f$? Only because of **both** (1) and (2) being infinite, so that their subtraction produces "$+\infty-\infty$" which can mean anything or nothing. If just one of the integrals in (1)-(2) is finite, we have the conclusion of Fubini's theorem already.

Stated as a contrapositive: if the equality of iterated integrals fails (be they finite or infinite), all integrals in (1)-(2) are infinite.

Here is a concrete example, taken from Wikipedia article [Failure of Fubini's theorem for non-integrable functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions): 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $$
Both iterated integrals are finite and they are unequal. Both the positive and negative parts of the function integrate to $\infty$.

Comment: Why is this strongly downvoted, but with no comments? Is it wrong?

Comment: @Katie Long story. The answer is correct.

Comment: The downvotes are entirely in regards to your 'vigilance' mission? I don't understand how someone could disagree with deleting terrible questions(I likely have a few myself), even if they have attached good answers. Keep up the good work with both your answers and your efforts.